# virtual directory address in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, virtual-directory

My applications appSettings is located in a virtual directory called "Resources"

how to reference it in root web.config files `<appSettings file="__??___">`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<appSettings file="~/Resources/ResourceFile" />
```